# Sliced string and char buffer are not equal

Tags: c

I want to extract the packet number from the received message and want to compare with originally sent packet_count and trying with following code

```
char string[] = "Hello client 0000!";    
char new[4];
char bufNew[4];
int i=0;
int count=0;
int num=0;
int packet_counter=0;

for (i=13;i<17;i++)
{
    new[count] = string[i];
    count = count+1;
}
new[4]='\0';
printf("Sliced no is: %s\n",new);
sprintf(bufNew, "%04d", packet_counter);
bufNew[4]='\0';

printf("packet counter is: %s\n",bufNew);

printf("String compare result: %d\n",strcmp(new,bufNew));
```

Although the output look same, strings are different.

Output:

```
Sliced no is: 0000                                                                                                            
packet counter is: 0000                                                                                                       
String compare result: 48
```

Please guide how to make both these strings equal.

Comment: make `new` and `bufNew` 5 characters or use `strncmp`. Your 4 character strings have no space for the null termination byte.

Comment: `new[4]` and `bufNew[4]` is out of bounds.

Comment: Yup - bean counting again:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that `sprintf(bufNew, "%04d", packet_counter);` overwrites the terminating 0 of `new` (since as others said, it is used out of its bounds). Try moving the `printf("Sliced no is: %s\n",new);` down below `bufNew[4]='\0';` to see it for yourself.

To fix it, `new`and `bufNew` needs to be declared with size `5`:

```
   char new[5];
   char bufNew[5];
```